# Получение данных с API и ошибка CORS

Tags: javascript, json, cors

Всем привет.

```
async function test() {
let response = await fetch('http://site.com', {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'exmaple': 'example'
  }
});
const data = await response.json();
return data;
}
test().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Есть вот такой код по запросы данных с сайта.
Выдает ошибка: Access to fetch at 'http://site.com' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Помогите понять в чем проблема понятным языком) Я просто впервые этим занимаюсь и многого не понимаю(

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы нашла решение, возможно кому-то оно поможет.
Можно добавить в код сразу после метода.

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```